# writing results to a file, some go on to the next line. python

Tags: python

I am writing the output of a function to a file, how ever if the number that is written has an e+01 at the end it writes one of the numbers on to the next line. for example

```
 0.12605695   1.64761066   1.55001798   0.01785089  15.80005801
 0.12231149   1.65899943   1.56369755   0.01511221  10.45653689
 0.1238494   1.67704048  1.59633667  0.00687468  0.96146016
 1.10437450e-01   1.62918081e+00   1.56024230e+00   1.82792879e-03
 -2.05519064e+00
 1.04326863e-01   1.63545256e+00   1.58687599e+00  -4.50753949e-03
 -6.40408013e+00
```

There should be five numbers per line, here is the part of my code where i write the numbers to a file,

```
 kop=open('new.txt', 'w')
 results=PCA(kk)
 res=results.mu
 print results.mu
 kop.write(str(res)+'\n')
 kop.close()
```

how do I get them to write to the one line and not go onto the next?
I need them all on the correct line as when I used numpy.genfromtxt in a different piece of code it requires them to all be in the correct columns.

Comment: What is `kop`? Is it a regular file? What is the type of `results.mu`?

Comment: yeah kop is just kop=open('new.txt', 'w')

Comment: reuslts.mu is an array, produced from the PCA function of matplotlib

Comment: Is `results.mu` a NumPy array? Be aware that `str(<numpy array>)` is designed for console output, not structured output, and may alter its appearance unexpectedly so that it looks better on a terminal.

Comment: ah, on the PCA documentation it says its an numdims array, it is a numpy array.

Comment: i just needed to use res=np.ndarray.tolist(res) to turn the numpy array to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer, I just didnt realize it was a numpy array.

```
 kop=open('new.txt', 'w')
 results=PCA(kk)
 res=results.mu
 res=np.ndarray.tolist(res)
 print results.mu
 kop.write(str(res)+'\n')
 kop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `results.mu` is something that can be iterated like a normal list, this snippet should do what you need by utilizing the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('new.txt', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")
   writer.writerows(results.mu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of `result.mu` you may try to use `rstrip()`:

```
 results=PCA(kk)
 res=results.mu
 print results.mu
 for i,y in enumerate(result.mu):
     result[i] = y.rstrip()
 kop.write(str(res)+'\n')
 kop.close()
```